# SQL Query for counting number of times a unique user bought/used product unique

Tags: sql, count, pivot, unique

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
Table Farm
User | Product
1      Apple
1      Orange
1      Apple
2      Grape
2      Grape
3      Apple
4      Orange
3      Grape
2      Apple
```

I'm relatively a noob at sql so I'm trying to figure out how to to create a sql query that results in this:

```
User | Apple | Grape | Orange
1       2       0      1
2       1       2      0
3       1       1      0
4       0       0      1
```

Is this possible?

I'm able to count the unique distinct purchases using this:

```
WITH cte as (
SELECT 
    USER,
    PRODUCT
FROM Farm
)
SELECT 
    USER
    COUNT(Product) as "Product Counts"
FROM CTE
GROUP BY USER
ORDER BY "Product Counts" DESC
```

Comment: Look up the PIVOT functionality.

Comment: Which database do you use?

Answer (score 0):

As Brad said above, this is the PIVOT functionality.

Since you are a "relative noob" though, I will help with your use case and you can branch out from there.

First I recreate your table (this is probably not efficient, but it works).

```
create or replace temp view createsampledata as
with definearrays as
(
select array(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,3,2) as theusers
  , array('Apple','Orange','Apple','Grape','Grape','Apple','Orange','Grape','Apple') as products
)
, createuserlist as
(
select theindex+1 as theposition, theuser, products
from definearrays
lateral view posexplode(theusers) as theindex,theuser
)
select theuser, element_at(products,theposition) as Product
from createuserlist
```

Then I select from that and PIVOT:

```
select *
from createsampledata
PIVOT (
  count(*)
  for product in ('Apple','Orange','Grape')
  )
order by theuser
```

This will give the desired output, except with null instead of 0.

If you want to replace the null with 0, you can do this instead:

```
select theuser
  , nvl(Apple,0) as Apple
  , nvl(Orange,0) as Orange
  , nvl(Grape,0) as Grape
from createsampledata
PIVOT (
  count(*)
  for product in ('Apple','Orange','Grape')
  )
order by theuser
```

An important thing to know about PIVOT is that the from statement includes the pivot. So your select statement comes from that, not from createsampledata only.

The bad thing is you have to write out the apple/orange/grape part yourself. I believe in SQL Server, you can dynamically pivot, but not otherwise.